# How can I change another field when I update one DataGridView field?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 fields in my SQL table: `Name` and `Status`. When I update or change anything from `Name` on the datagridview and data set. it should update `Status` as well. How do I do that?

Comment: There are many options to do that. What value you need to set in `Status` field after setting `Name`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Modified. Any modifications to a name will set its status to modified.

Comment: You can use these options: **(1)** You can do it in SQL Server using `Trigger`.  **(2)** You can do it  handling `CellValueChanged` event of `DataGridView`. **(3)**  If you are using typed dataset you can do it overridng `OnColumnChanged` of the data table. **(4)** You can do it handling `ColumnChanged` event of your data table.

Comment: Can you show me how to do number 2?

Comment: Yes.  I'll post an example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options to do that.

For example:

- You can do it in SQL Server using Trigger.
- You can do it handling CellValueChanged event of DataGridView.
- If you are using typed dataset you can do it overridng OnColumnChanged of the data table.
- You can do it handling ColumnChanged event of your data table.

**CellValueChanged Example:**

Based on your comment as an example for using [`CellValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Suppose 0 is the index of Name column and 1 is the index of Status Column
    //We check if the change is in a datagrid view row and in name column 
    //Then we change value of Status column.
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = "Modified";
}
```

Or even if you didn't add `Status` column to the grid you can use such code to change it:

```
((DataRowView)this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)["Status"] = "Modified";
```

**ColumnChanged Example:**

As an example for [`ColumnChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
void table1_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the event is raised for Name column
    if (e.Column.ColumnName == "Name")
        e.Row["Status"] = "Modified";
}
```